# Create AutoNumber for Duplicate Field

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-server, conditional

How do I create autonumber in SharePoint List where the field contain duplicates. I want to use workflow with condition to identify these duplicate items and set the ID.
For example, there are several item and type with the same name. So, I want it add an ID according to the item and type. (first Item A and type A1 = 1, second Item A and type A1 = 2).

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: You can create a SharePoint Designer with the Workflow 2013 engine. Are you talking about SharePoint 2013?

Comment: yes.. can you give an example on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to create an Event Receiver. It is like a database trigger. More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: the thing is I'm a trainee and there's limitation on what I can do. I really need to find a way to do it using sharepoint designer.. thanks anyway..

Comment: I think you cannot do it with SharePoint Designer ... :-(